# Overwriting file issue using PHP

Tags: php, file, overwrite

I have to write a file, in order to increase a value, but sometimes (when the file is opened two times in a row) it increases only by one instead of two.

This is part of the script executed two times in a row:

```
include "changevar.php";//declare the changevar function
include $file;//get user's impressions
changevar("impressions",$impressions+1,$file,1);//increase the impressions by 1
```

And this is the `changevar.php` file:

```
<?
function changevar($varname,$newval,$filename,$type)
{
    while(!$fp=fopen($filename,"c+"))
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }
    while(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }
    $contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));
    ftruncate($fp,0);
    rewind($fp);
    eval(substr(substr($contents,2),0,-2));
    $$varname=$newval;
    if($type==0)//avoid reading this, in this case $type equals to 1
    {
        $u=str_replace("\"","\\\"",$u);
        $p=str_replace("\"","\\\"",$p);
        $t=str_replace("\"","\\\"",$t);
        $d=str_replace("\"","\\\"",$d);
        $text="<?\$o=$o;\$u=\"$u\";\$c=$c;\$m=$m;\$p=\"$p\";\$C=$C;\$id=\"$id\";\$t=\"$t\";\$d=\"$d\";\$O=$O;?>";
    }
    else//true, $type equals to 1
    {
        $text="<?\$impressions=$impressions;\$clickunici=$clickunici;\$clicknulli=$clicknulli;\$creditiguadagnati=$creditiguadagnati;\$creditiacquistati=$creditiacquistati;\$creditiutilizzati=$creditiutilizzati;?>";
    }
    fwrite($fp,$text);
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

As I just said, the script works fine, except if it is executed two times in a row.

I think that the problem is in `$contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));`, because it reads the files before it is written.

I already used the `flock` function, but it doesn't solve this problem.

So, how can I fix the code?

Comment: You can create mutex in `sys_get_temp_dir()` and delete it at the end. If it already exists, wait random time.

Comment: Why such a general question? Why not just find and fix whatever is keeping `flock()` from working correctly?

Comment: Do you *really* need to be opening/reading/writing/closing a file multiple times in a single execution? The stability of your code, the IO load on your server, the responsiveness of the script, and *your sanity* would be better off if you move the commitment of data to file to the end of your script where it happens only once per execution, and only if necessary. Otherwise you'd probably be better off using a database for simplicity and atomicity of the transactions.

Comment: @Sammitch it's a counter, so i think I need to do this... If you have a better solution just write it here :)

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov good idea, I'll think about that if I can't use the flock function

Comment: `flock` will block until it succeeds, so no point in calling it over and over in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're doing since you only give bits and pieces of your code, and you don't show the content of the file read; but if you want to increment the value in the file, you should be adding one to **a number you read from the locked file**-- not writing an argument (`$impressions+1`) that you pass to `changevar()` from the outside. Rethink the logic of your code and fix it.